# Leave out Nulls when using Case When statement

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to get rid of lines that have the Null value while still keeping the columns how they are

I tried this but I get invalid identifier for the where statements. I'm doing this in hopes of getting rid of duplicate rows

```
select distinct b.segment1 as "Project Code", b.NAME,
 (case when a.CLASS_CATEGORY = 'Division' then a.CLASS_CODE end) as "Division",
 (case when a.CLASS_CATEGORY = 'City State' then a.CLASS_CODE end) as "CityState"
        from PROD.PROJECT_CLASSES a
            inner join prod.projects_all b
                 on a.project_id = b.project_id
where Division is not null
and CityState is not null
order by b.segment1
```

Comment: You can't refer to a column expression alias like `"CityState"` in the same level of query, except in an order-by clause. You can repeat the case expression, or more simply use a subquery and filter that. I'd also recommend avoiding quoted identifiers if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the actual column rather then the alias. Try this,

```
select distinct b.segment1 as "Project Code", b.NAME,
 (case when a.CLASS_CATEGORY = 'Division' then a.CLASS_CODE end) as "Division",
 (case when a.CLASS_CATEGORY = 'City State' then a.CLASS_CODE end) as "CityState"
        from PROD.PROJECT_CLASSES a
            inner join prod.projects_all b
                 on a.project_id = b.project_id
where (a.CLASS_CATEGORY = 'Division' or 
        a.CLASS_CATEGORY = 'City State')
and a.CLASS_CODE is not null
order by b.segment1
```